# Skipping fetch if network offline with if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set a fetch that gets information on location from a third party API.

Now when I go offline I can see errors in the console as failed requests. How do I skip the fetch part when the connection offline?

I have tried using `if/else` statements with `window.navigator.online` but it only reads the else part.

```
getMarkerInfo(marker) {
    var self = this;
    var clientId = "hidden";
    var clientSecret = "hidden";
    var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=" +
        clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&v=20130815&ll=" +
        marker.getPosition().lat() + "," + marker.getPosition().lng() + "&limit=1";

    // If connection online then fetch data else inform
    if (window.navigator.online != true) {
        console.log("false");
    } else {
        console.log("true");
        fetch(url)
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        self.state.infowindow.setContent("Sorry cannot find data");
                        return;
                    }

                    // get name and location in info map
                    response.json().then(function(data) {
                        var location_data = data.response.venues[0];
                        var name = location_data.name;
                        var address = location_data.location.address;
                        self.state.infowindow.setContent('<b>' + name + '</b>' + '<br>' + address);
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function(err) {
                self.state.infowindow.setContent("Sorry cannot find data");
            });
    }

}
```

> net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Comment: It's `window.navigator.onLine` with an uppercase L

Comment: Isnt it `window.navigator.onLine` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.navigator.onLine` should have an uppercase 'L' in it.

So the if statement should be:

```
if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
  console.log("No connection!")
} else {
  // fetch()...
}
```